# Unity Dash disappears when I type "w"

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, unity-dash

The prompt area of Unity Dash **disappears** when I type "w" in the search bar.

Example:
A single 'w' (lowercase), or a sequence like "test w" closes the area. However it doesn't happen for "W" (uppercase).

Does anyone know how to debug in this situation?
(Is xkb possibly related?)

Comment: I've finally figured out that the keyboard shortcut to "Close window" is related to this problem. I set it to "Super+w", and if I change it to "Super+q" then the above behavior remains but with "q" instead of "w". I will report it to some BTS.